# change color of first word

Tags: html, css

I am working in wordpress. I want to set site name in two colors.

My html code is :

```
<h1 class="site_title"> Pal Enterprice </h1>
```

Here I want to set **Pal** color as red and **Enterprice** color as  blue. So what css have to write?

Comment: using this css we can change only color of **p** not Pal.

Answer (score 0):

Please check this snippet code.

```css
h1 {
  color: #00f;
}


h1 span {
  color: #f00;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="site_title"> <span>Pal</span> Enterprice </h1>
```

Comment: I dont want to use any tag inside h1 tag.